# Overloading operator + in my own arithmetic

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I have the following problem:
suppose that I'm trying to implement my own class MyInt, which is capable of holding large numbers (I know about BigNum implementation - this is just a practice). I have implemented constructors that accept int, unsigned long, unsigned long long etc. - hence my question.

I'm trying to overload the operator +, with the following declaration:

```
        friend MyInt operator+(const MyInt &, const MyInt &);
```

inside the class.

It works fine when I'm adding to MyInt's, however I would like it to work in cases like

```
MyInt x(0);
x = x + 1;
```

When I call it like that, I get the following output:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘MyInt’ and ‘int’)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve that

**Edit:**

Here's sample code, written by me. The constructor is **explicit**

```
using namespace std;

class MyInt {
    public:
        MyInt() {};
        explicit MyInt(int) {};
        friend MyInt operator+(const MyInt &x, const MyInt &y) {
            MyInt result;
            cout << "operator + " << endl;
            return result;
        }   
};

int main() {
    MyInt x;
    x = x + x; //this is fine
    x = x + 1; //this is not
}
```

Comment: try using `x = x + MyInt(1);`

Comment: well, to add `MyInt` and an `int` you need an `operator+(MyInt&,int)`

Comment: ...or `MyInt` sounds very much like you could provide a constructor `MyInt(int)` which will make conversions possible

Comment: This sounds like you have an implicit conversion to `int`. With conversions both ways implicit the expression is just ambiguous. Implicit is bad, explicit is good.

Comment: How many `operator+` have you defined?

Comment: @songyuanyao only one

Comment: You need to provide a complete but minimal example that people can try. Without it  you just get silly suggestions like the three current answers. Voted to close as lacking example.

Comment: Sorry guys, all the answers are poor. Please can the OP clarify the question?

Comment: @Jytug I tried a demo [here](http://ideone.com/8GcTg4).

Comment: @songyuanyao thank you

Comment: @Jytug So is your constructor `explicit`?

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes - I'm trying to avoid using char or bool in the constructors

Answer (score 1):

The construct is `explicit`, means the implicit conversion from `int` to `MyInt` is not allowed, and then `operator+(const MyInt &, const MyInt &)` couldn't be applied for the call of `MyInt + int`.

**Solution1**

Add overload version of `operator+`, such as:

```
MyInt operator+(const MyInt &, int); 
MyInt operator+(int, const MyInt &);
```

**Solution2**

Remove `explicit` from the constructor.

Comment: Re (1), it's impractical to provide overloads for all argument type combinations.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf OP has his reason to use an explicit ctor, so I put it as 1st solution. -> " I'm trying to avoid using char or bool in the constructors"

Answer (score 1):

Given the following problem:

```
using namespace std;

class MyInt {
    public:
        MyInt() {};
        explicit MyInt(int) {};
        friend MyInt operator+(const MyInt &x, const MyInt &y) {
            MyInt result;
            cout << "operator + " << endl;
            return result;
        }   
};

int main() {
    MyInt x;
    x = x + x; //this is fine
    x = x + 1; //this is not
}
```

… a reasonable solution is to make the converting constructor implicit, i.e. non-`explicit`.

For example, `std::string` allows you to construct a `std::string` implicitly from a literal. That provides a great practical benefit. But then, there is no problem with `s + s` because there's no built-in `+` for pointer arguments, and `std::string` doesn't provide implicit conversion back to `char const*`.

Still, I think an implicit conversion *to* the big-number class makes sense. Make the opposite conversion, to built-in type, `explicit` (if it's implicit then this problem pops up again). And preferably named.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add an `operator+(const MyInt & lhs, int rhs);`

Another solution is to add a `MyInt(int)` constructor that is then implicitly called by the compiler.

Comment: The first is impractical, the second is already done.

Comment: Given your constructor is explicit, the implicit conversion is not possible. That's the issue ;)